# JS inside angular script tag not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to work with jquery ui to include the jquery ui calender widget but the script tag in the ng-view template is not working.

```
...
<div style="padding:0px 20px;">
    ...
        ...
        ...
                <label for="eventDate">Event Date</label>
                <input id="eventDate" type="text" datakeys ng-model="event.date" placeholder="Event Date..." required/>

            ...
        ...
   ...
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("y=test");
    $("#eventDate").datepicker();
</script>
</div>
```

Is there something I am not doing right?

Comment: Add document.ready() and try it should work

Comment: If you're going to use angularjs then use it. this is jQuery question and has nothing to do with angular

Comment: no @Ali786 this is not going to work, and even if it will, it's still all wrong

Comment: why you are using jquery datepicker in angular js? there is a angular version available.

Comment: Since you're already started getting those terrible answers - http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepickerPopup use a native angular popup